# Calculate voltage of a 16-bit differential ADC that gives a two's complement value

Tags: adc, stm32, embedded, texas-instruments

I am working with a 16-bit differential [ADC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc161s626.pdf) and I would like to know the difference between this latter and a single ended ADC especially: How to calculate voltage from the ADC value ?

Is it like this:

```
Voltage = IN- + Vref x Code/2^n-1
```

**EDITED:** According to the datasheet, the ADC gives a two's complement value. How to calculate voltage from this value ?

Comment: Usually the output format is in 2's complement.

Comment: From data sheet page 16: **For example, the size of one LSB is equal to [(2 x VREF) / 2^n], which is 152.6 μV where n is 16 bits and VREF is 5V.** And as LongPham has said, 2's complement format

Comment: How to convert this 2's complement value to a voltage?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: 2's complement is the standard way to represent a number that can go positive or negative. Just make sure the Voltage variable is a signed integer, and it will give you a positive/negative voltage. No conversion required. The formula you provided is correct.

Comment: @Oliver Not quite, he's missing some parentheses. I think the variable type should be 16-bit signed int.

Comment: @LongPham good shout. I parsed it fine, but I think the C compiler would be a different story ;)

Comment: Note: your program doesn't need to know the voltage. Raw ADC values are fine for all purposes of writing a program. You only need to convert to volt if you plan to display the result to humans. Scaling internal data needlessly is a very common beginner bug.

Comment: It's not clear whether you are having difficulty interpreting the the two bytes of data from the ADC, or if your problem is the formula to convert the (already well understood) twos complement data into a floating point representation of the actual voltage. Also, I presume you are using a microprocessor/controller to do all this, so what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear in your question whether your main problem is with...

- understanding twos complement.
- understanding how to load the incoming SPI data into a variable.
- understanding differential ADC measurements.
- understanding how to convert ADC counts into a voltage using a scale factor.

Let's start with the first point.  Twos complement is the native format used by most microprocessors to store signed integers.  Once you have the value in twos complement in a signed integer variable (int16_t) there is often no need to convert it to anything else.  The processor can do math on it directly.

As for reading the data over SPI, the timing diagram from the ADC datasheet shows that the value read out of the ADC over SPI bus is just two padding bits followed by the twos complement value.  The only thing you might need to do is shift and combine the incoming bytes into one 16-bit value.  Without information regarding what processor you are using its hard to say how that would look.

[image]

Regarding differential ADC measurements, the ADC just takes the difference between the +IN and the -IN pins and tells you how many counts that is.  The value output by the ADC is...

$$ X = \frac{((+IN) - (-IN)) * 2^{15}}{V_{REF}}$$

Where X is the 16-bit ADC reading that comes in over SPI.

And conversely...

$$ V = ((+IN) - (-IN)) = \frac{V_{REF}}{2^{15}} * X$$

Where V is the differential input voltage between the + and - input pins.

To convert ADC counts (X) into a voltage V you just need to multiply by a scale factor.

In C code the calculation looks like.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#define VREF (5.0)
const double scale_factor =  VREF / 32768.0;
...
int16_t X;
//Some code goes here to put the value from SPI into X
...
//Convert count in twos complement into volts.
double V;    
V = X * scale_factor
```

Note that this conversion could also be done more efficiently with scaled integers instead of floating point, but I didn't want to make the example overly hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Differential or single ended has nothing to do with your conversion.

**Differential:** Voltage being converted to is `(In+)-(In-)`

**Single Ended:** Voltage being converted to is `Vin`

```
int16_t code=read_ADC(); 
float voltage=code*Vref/(2^16-1)
```

`n` bit devises the range to `(2^n-1)` "buckets", so each bucket is `Vref/(2^n-1)`

Comment: (2^n -1) vs (2^n). Never-ending controversy ;)

Answer (score 0):

A 16-bit differential ADC result consists of 1 sign bit (+/-) and 15 bit value; So the whole output range would be `-32768 ~ +32767`. you can use the formula provided by doubleE's answer to calculate that.

Example 1: you get +1500 from ADC conversion. with a 5V reference, the voltage difference would be `(1500/32767)*5 = 228mV`. It means the positive input is 228mV higher than the negative input. (e.g. the negative input is getting 1V, the positive is getting 1.228V).

Example 2: you get -2500 from ADC conversion. with a 5V reference, the voltage difference would be `(-2500/32768)*5 = -381mV`. It means the positive input is 381mV lower than the negative input. (e.g. the negative input is getting 2V, the positive is getting 1.619V).

In single-ended conversion the negative input is connected to ADC's ground so any value is usually referenced to 0; So when the positive is 228mV higher than the negative (now 0) it means the positive input is sensing 228mV.